How to animate a Balance Spring with Geonodes
It seems the question on how to animate a Balance Spring (or Coil Spring / Hairspring) as used in a watch escapement using Blender has been asked a few times before (here, here and here) but unfortunately it has never been answered correctly.
Usually the answers involve bone weights or hooks to a spiral curve or mesh to a rotating bone with some falloff. While this looks ok for rotations under 90-110 degrees, the effect breaks apart when using bigger angles:

The reason is that in the real world the metal doesn't 'stretch' during the rotation, but bends out of its resting shape between minimum and maximum oscillation, pulling the rotations inwards or pushing them outwards respectively so the 'bone weights approach' can never be physically accurate.
In reality many such Balance Springs in watches have an amplitude of over 240 degrees, like the +/-480 end-to-end amplitude seen here, up to 310 degrees for high-end movements.
So we need a new approach. I'm thinking something with Geonodes is probably possible (some variation of this maybe?) but I've never used Geonodes before.
Any ideas/pointers on how to approach this problem?

I have health issues right now (famous last words), but you can probably take a look at Ciechanow.ski blog post about mechanical watches and inspect the javascript behind 4th or 23rd ("Balance" section) embed. Then it's a matter of porting the code to geometry nodes.

Okay I'll look at that - thank you for the link. In the meantime I hope you feel better soon!

@MarkusvonBroady Can you give a proper set up for this effect with realistic size of the spring?

For reference, here's a decent solution:
https://youtu.be/ZXkcrHDQPrs
To animate, just put values of the 'mix' node in an animation:

Amplitude of Inner Spring to create the base rotation
Shrinking/Growing of Spiral to get a realistic look
Offset of outer spring part to get the typical 'swing' of the outer rotations


You will need to create also this nodegroup, that 'spreads' an offset over a set number of vertices (a bit like a bevel), so that you can manage the various offsets easily:

I'd be happy to upload a sample file if there is a need.

Can you please upload the sample file? It's very hard to understand what's going on here
